# Would an Eternal Ring tag prove useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

The other day, I was going to go ask a Question about an old PS2 RPG game I got back into, Eternal Ring, but I realized there is no tag for it!

I am not sure it would be an extremely popular tag, since it came out in 2001, and it wasn't too popular when it came out. Still, I think it would be used some. So, is it a good idea, or a waste?

Comment: We aren't limited on how many tags we have. Tags need questions, you can't have a tag without having at least one question that uses it. So ask your question, tag it appropriately (or get someone to tag it if you can't create them yourself) and go from there.

Comment: For reference, you'll need [300 reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to create tags yourself, so just tag with the platform ([pc], [xbox], [ps2] etc) and request someone create the tag for you in the comments :). See also: [Posting a question for a game that doesn't yet have a tag](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5504/28182)

Answer (score 3):

There are many tags with only one question using them, so while the tag might not be useful for other than a couple questions, it should cause no harm.